# Moving files after processing

Tags: python, shutil

Hi Trying to move logs that are finished being processed but I think I'm using shutil wrong.

```
import shutil

path = '/logs/'
finDir = '/complete/'

# parse loop
def getUniquePath(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
       if..processing log 
       shutil.move(filename, finDir) #moves completed files
```

I keep getting errors that file does not exist.

So I added a print statement after the loop and it correctly prints out the filename and the destination so I'm thinking that I am just using shutil.move incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: try doing `os.chdir(path_to_file)` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine `path` with `filename` unless you are in the `/logs/` directory.

Otherwise, file searching is done in the current directory; which cause file not found, or wrong file manipulation (if there was the file with the same name in the current directory)

Using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os
import shutil

path = '/logs/'
finDir = '/complete/'

# parse loop
def getUniquePath(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
       ..
       shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename), finDir)
       #           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ah nice this looks great. Will shutil.move account for say.. the file exists in the destination directory? Would it make sense for me to add a "Try:" condition on the move incase there is an error I'd like it to continue on. What would be the best way for that? @falsetru

Comment: its so strange. So I added `try: shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename), finDir) except : pass ` and only 1 file got moved over. If I remove the try and except everything gets moved over @falsetru

Comment: @chowpay, Please post a separated question with the updated code.